# Jenkins Build Taking Too Long

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Once upon a time, they had Jenkins build our program in minutes. Now it's taking over 2 hours. I've copied below the area where it seems to hang up. From my understanding, it's building successfully, but it's held up when moving some files around. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
Done Building Project "C:\dev\cd\src\webservices\PricingEngineService\PricingEngineService\PricingEngineService.csproj" (Package target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.67
[workspace] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\CDIUSE~1.CLE\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins2991160982461640193.ps1'"
[workspace] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\CDIUSE~1.CLE\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins3998493390681688005.ps1'"
[10:27:53] Using gulpfile C:\dev\cd\src\jedi\gulpfile.js
[10:27:53] Starting 'deleteDistFolder'...
Deleted folder:  [ 'C:\\dev\\cd\\src\\jedi\\dist' ]
[10:27:54] Finished 'deleteDistFolder' after 528 ms
[10:27:54] Starting 'sass-build'...
[10:27:54] Finished 'sass-build' after 107 ms
[10:27:54] Starting 'minifyHTML'...
[10:27:54] Finished 'minifyHTML' after 360 ms
[10:27:54] Starting 'build'...
[10:27:54] Finished 'build' after 33 ms
[10:27:54] Starting 'build-app-module'...
[10:27:55] Finished 'build-app-module' after 160 ms
[10:27:55] Starting 'copy-files'...
[10:27:58] Finished 'copy-files' after 3.01 s
[10:27:58] Starting 'bower-install'...
[10:27:58] Using cwd: ./src/
[10:27:58] Using bower dir: lib
[10:28:10] Finished 'bower-install' after 13 s
[10:28:10] Starting 'bower'...
[10:28:17] Finished 'bower' after 6.43 s
[10:28:17] Starting 'dist'...
[10:28:17] Finished 'dist' after 2.93 Î¼s
[workspace] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\CDIUSE~1.CLE\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins3818291352140264878.ps1'"
[workspace] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\CDIUSE~1.CLE\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins3645201150751239660.ps1'"
[workspace] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\CDIUSE~1.CLE\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins8091378399438661373.ps1'"
Invoke-Command : Cannot find path 'C:\dev\cd\src\cdi-conf\scripts\DesployIIS.PS1' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\cdiuser.cd\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins8091378399438661373.ps1:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName devopsweb01 -FilePath \dev\cd\s ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\dev\cleardem...\DesployIIS.PS1:String) [Invoke-Command], ItemNotFoun 
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: The errormessage says your filepath is missing... it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it can't find your file:

> ```
> Invoke-Command : Cannot find path
> 'C:\dev\cd\src\cdi-conf\scripts\DesployIIS.PS1' because it does not
> exist.
> ```

But it also says this error comes from the script `C:\Users\cdiuser.cd\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins8091378399438661373.ps1`.

This is a temporary file created by Jenkins, which means that this is likely a PowerShell build step in the Jenkins job/pipeline.

In Jenkins, as you navigate the web interface to look at the configuration, this will be just a text box, and the script contents will be in there. When it runs it generates a temporary file on the worker.

So you need to look at that code in the job, and determine where it has referenced the file `'C:\dev\cd\src\cdi-conf\scripts\DesployIIS.PS1'` and then figure out why that file doesn't exist on the target worker server (or why this script thinks it should exist), and fix that issue.

Comment: To add to the above, if you've got multiple 'Windows PowerShell' steps, you can add `Write-Output "Step Name/Description"` to identify each step in the Jenkins Console.

Comment: This is definitely the right way to troubleshoot. Just going to throw this out there as one thing to check... `Desploy` seems like it's maybe a mistyped `Deploy`?